# Having an image filling a button in Titanium

Tags: button, titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm working with Titanium studio on an Alloy project. In one of my pages, I would like to have a button with an image inside, an image that would fill the button.

What I'm doing now is :

```
<Button image="/images/micro.png"/>
```

It successfully retrieve the image, but it's displayed really small :

[image]

I also tried to do the same in JS :

```
win.add(Ti.UI.createButton({image:"/images/micro.png"}));
```

But I ended with the same result..

So, is there a way to manage the size of those images?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634605/titanium-image-auto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you wouldn't use **backgroundImage** you can create your own Button:
example :

```
<Alloy>
    //Your stuff ....
    <View id="button">
        <ImageView id="buttImage" image="yourpath/yourIcon.png"/>
        <Label id='buttTitle" text="Button Title"/>
    <View/>
    //Your Stuff ...
</Alloy>
```

the in style.tss

```
"#button":{
        layout:'horizontal'
        backgroundColor:"##3498db",
        height:70,
        width:300
        }
"#buttImage":{
           height:50,
           width:50,
           left:10
           }
"#buttTitle":{
            font:{
                 fontSize:19,
                 color:"#000"
                }
```

and in .js file you add you click event Listener :

```
$.button.addEventListener("click",clickFunction);
```

Also you can take a look at this awesome [widget](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.button) where you can add icons and many customization ...

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for! I would gladly upvote your unswer but I don't have enough reputation .. However I accept it!
I used the widget solution :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use **backgroundImage** Property of button to achieve this. Here is the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button-property-backgroundImage)

Comment: Thx for the answer, however, the backgroundImage property replace the button skin, it does not add itself to it..